# Rails I18n ActiveRecord model attributes after migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-i18n

I started creating an app, and planned out my basic scaffolding. Let's say I created this resource:

```bash
rails g scaffold CircusAnimal fieldOne:string fieldTwo:string
```

I'm using Rails I18n to translate the labels on my forms using:

```yaml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      circus_animal:
        fieldOne: Breed
        fieldTwo: Trainer
```

So far so good, when I generate a form with all the fields for a model translations are being picked up correctly:

```rb
<%= form.fields_for :circus_animals do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :fieldOne %>
  <%= f.text_field :fieldOne %>
  <%= f.label :fieldTwo %>
  <%= f.text_field :fieldTwo %>
<% end %>
```

Then I decided I needed another field for this form, so I ran a migration:

```
rails g migration add_fieldThree_to_circusAnimal fieldThree:integer
rails db:migrate
```

I added the new field to permitted fields in the controller, and I added it in the view.

```rb
<%= form.fields_for :circus_animal do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :fieldOne %>
  <%= f.text_field :fieldOne %>
  <%= f.label :fieldTwo %>
  <%= f.text_field :fieldTwo %>
+ <%= f.label :fieldThree %>
+ <%= f.number_field :fieldThree %>
<% end %>
```

I also added a translation in `en.yml`:

```yaml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      circus_animal:
        fieldOne: Breed
        fieldTwo: Trainer
+       fieldThree: Age
```

However the label for `fieldThree` is not getting translated. I have tried to clobber assets, I have tried running `rails db:schema:cache:clear`, and I have tried running this in the rails console:

```
CircusAnimal.connection.schema_cache.clear!
CircusAnimal.reset_column_information
```

If I run `CircusAnimal.columns` I correctly see the `fieldThree` column.

How can I get the newly added field to be translated just like the previous two fields that were initially scaffolded?

Comment: Please confirm what the name of those columns looks like. Are the names in camelCase or with under_scores? Please make sure that the name in the db matches the name in the view and the locale file.

Comment: @spickermann I've updated the question with more precise casing for the Model, the fields, and the translations in `en.yml`. The first two fields are translated correctly. The third field added later with a migration is not getting translated...

Comment: my bad, I see what happened. The resource in question (let's call it `CircusAnimal`) belongs to another resource (let's call it `Circus`), and the form fields were included on the view page for the `Circus` resource. I added the `:fieldThree` on the view for the `Circus` resource and not on the view for the `CircusAnimal` resource: thus my custom `i18n-tasks` scanner was associating `:fieldThree` with the `Circus` resource rather than the `CircusAnimal`. To fix I simply added `:fieldThree` to the view for `CircusAnimal`, the scanner picked it up and correctly associated it with `CircusAnimal`

Comment: I suggest following Ruby‘s and Ruby on Rails‘ naming conventions which are: variables are named with underscores, like field_one. Not following these naming conventions might cause issues when using gems or working together with other developers.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I see what happened. The resource in question (let's call it `CircusAnimal`) belongs to another resource (let's call it `Circus`), and therefore the form fields for `CircusAnimal` were included on the view page for the `Circus` resource, along with the `Circus` form fields. I added `:fieldThree` on the view for the `Circus` resource and not on the view for the `CircusAnimal` resource: thus my custom `i18n-tasks` scanner was associating `:fieldThree` with the `Circus` resource rather than the `CircusAnimal` resource. To fix I simply added `:fieldThree` to the view for `CircusAnimal`, the scanner picked it up and correctly associated it with `CircusAnimal`. Now when I translate it in `en.yml` under the correct resource, the translation is correctly showing in the view. Sorry, dumb mistake! I figured it out by trying to do the translation in the rails console with `I18n.t('activerecords.attributes.circus_animal.fieldThree')` and I got an error that the translation key was missing. That got me to notice that the key was under the wrong resource, because it had been picked up from the view for the `Circus` resource!